# Disk Utility Reports Invalid Key Order on APFS Volume (macOS Catalina)

Tags: disk-utility, catalina, apfs

On the latest version of macOS Catalina as of this writing (10.15.2), Disk Utility is reporting that I have invalid key order on my snapshots:

```
Running First Aid on “iMac HD - Data” (disk2s1)

Verifying the startup volume will cause this computer to stop responding.

Verifying file system.
Volume could not be unmounted.
Using live mode.
Performing fsck_apfs -n -l -x /dev/rdisk2s1
Checking the container superblock.
Checking the fusion superblock.
Checking the EFI jumpstart record.
Checking the space manager.
Checking the space manager free queue trees.
Checking the object map.
Checking the Fusion data structures.
Checking volume.
Checking the APFS volume superblock.
The volume iMac HD - Data was formatted by hfs_convert (945.200.129) and last modified by apfs_kext (1412.61.1).
Checking the object map.
Checking the snapshot metadata tree.
Checking the snapshot metadata.
Checking snapshot 1 of 3 (com.apple.apfs.purgatory.9458b)
error: btn: invalid key order (6) oid 463237 / oxid 0 / level 0 / flags 0x2
    previous key: 0x2004000009962b4b

    current key:  0x2004000000080218

    next key:     0x20040000099821e2

Snapshot is invalid.
The volume /dev/rdisk2s1 could not be verified completely.
File system check exit code is 0.
Restoring the original state found as mounted.

Operation successful.
```

This is on the new "Data" volume that Catalina creates for your files, aside from the read only system volume.

I have tried running Disk First Aid multiple times from Recovery and Internet Recovery, booted into Single User Mode and tried to run `fsck_apfs -y` from there, all to no avail. I also tried resetting PRAM/NVRAM and the SMC per AppleCare's advice, but I doubt this has anything to do with my APFS volumes.

Does anyone know how to get rid of these "purgatory" snaps so that disk first aid can run clean once more?

Comment: Resolving the snapshot issue will likely be tedious. Assuming that the container doesn't have any issues beside the offending snapshot, you may be able to recover your data using [`apfs-fuse`](https://github.com/sgan81/apfs-fuse). If no luck with that, try [my APFS tools](https://github.com/jivanpal/apfs-tools).

Comment: @rk15000 Did you ever resolve this issue? If so, could you perhaps post an answer with the steps you followed? Thanks!